# Testing on Lottie Android - Assert color

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, lottie

In my Android application, I used to have a ProgressBar that, in a test, would check the color assigned to the view.

```
  assertEquals(
            ColorStateList.valueOf(
                Color.parseColor("#FF5500")
            ),
            activity
                .findViewById<ProgressBar?>(R.id.progress)
                .indeterminateTintList
        )
```

So far, everything is correct, and the test passes.

Now, I have replaced the ProgressBar with a LottieAnimationView.

```
 <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    ...
    ...
 </com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView>
```

Logically, the test now fails.

I modify it as follows:

```
   assertEquals(
            ColorStateList.valueOf(
                Color.parseColor("#FF5500")
            ),
            activity
                .findViewById<LottieAnimationView?>(R.id.progress)
                .colorFilter
        )
```

But it still doesn't pass and indicates the following error:

```
Expected :ColorStateList{mStateSpecs=[[]]mColors=[-21999]mDefaultColor=-21999}
Actual   :null
```

I have also tried using .solidColor instead of .colorFilter, but in this case, it still doesn't pass and returns the following error:

```
Expected :ColorStateList{mStateSpecs=[[]]mColors=[-21999]mDefaultColor=-21999}
Actual   :0
```

Programmatically, you can assign the color to the LottieAnimationView as follows:

```
lottieAnimationView.addValueCallback(
        new KeyPath("**"),
        LottieProperty.COLOR_FILTER,
        frInfo -> new PorterDuffColorFilter(
                myCustomViewColor,
                PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP
        )
);
```

...But I don't see a way to perform this test on the LottieAnimationView.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.